# How can I add a RecordingController in a Jmeter project using Java api?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

How can I add a **NonTestElement** Proxy recording controller in a Jmeter project using Java api?  I am trying to do it in [THIS GITHUB PROJECT](https://github.com/djangofan/jmeter-jmx-create) but it is not working.  I am able to add a RecordingController, which is a container that stores the recorded items, but I am having trouble adding the non-test recording element to the test plan root element.  When I try to add the Proxy controller, it appears as a regular target RecordingController, which is not my intention.

I am using Jmeter 4.0:

```
// this RecordingController works fine
RecordingController recordingController = new RecordingController();
recordingController.setName("Recordings");
recordingController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, RecordController.class.getName());
recordingController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());

// this non-test ProxyControl is the one i cant get working
ProxyControl proxyController = new ProxyControl();
proxyController.setName("Proxy Recorder");
proxyController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ProxyControl.class.getName());
proxyController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());

ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
threadGroup.setName("Sample Thread Group");
....

TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
testPlanTree.add(proxyController);

HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
threadGroupHashTree.add(recordingController);
```

NOTE: while I look for an answer, I verify this actually worked by opening the resulting .jmx project file (generated from this Java code; see link to my project) in Jmeter 4.0.   If that doesn't work, then I don't consider this question answered.

Comment: I fixed my code to create a working jmx file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working, the right way to add proxy controller with the right GUI class `proxyController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ProxyControlGui.class.getName());`

Here's a working sample based on your code:

```
    RecordingController recordingController = new RecordingController();
    recordingController.setName("Recordings");
    recordingController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, RecordController.class.getName());
    recordingController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, RecordController.class.getName());

    ProxyControl proxyController = new ProxyControl();
    proxyController.setName("Proxy Recorder");
    proxyController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ProxyControl.class.getName());
    proxyController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ProxyControlGui.class.getName());

    ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
    LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
    loopController.setLoops(1);
    loopController.setFirst(true);
    loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
    loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
    loopController.initialize();
    // Thread Group

    threadGroup.setName("Sample Thread Group");
    threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
    threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
    threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

    TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
    testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());
    testPlan.addTestElement(proxyController);
    HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();
    testPlanTree.add(testPlan);

    HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
    threadGroupHashTree.add(recordingController);
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and it doesn't work.    I'll look some more this weekend because there must be a solution.  Maybe I will also try a different version of Jmeter but I doubt that will be the solution as I am using the 4.0 java api...

Comment: Can you write what is the error or not working. Because it works in my side. Do you expect it to execute a recording? Or you want to save to jmx file?

Comment: I want to save to a .jmx file, which it does, but I need Jmeter 4.0 to be capable of opening that file (as validation the format is correct).